# How to interrupt git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

For example, if I am on `feature` branch now, I want to rebase it to `master` branch, so I run the following command.

> git rebase master

As I have known, git will switch to branch master, find merge base of feature and master branch, and apply patches of feature branch to master branch one by one.

Now I encounter a conflict, I run `git difftool` to solve conflict. When solving conflict, I edit my source code to the merged status and I do not want the sequential patches. How can I finish `git rebase` now?

Comment: After a conflict resolution `git rebase --cont` or `git rebase --abort` to return back to the initial point

Comment: @user3159253, that means when I run `git add` to mark my resolved confliction and run `git rebase --abort`, git will switch to branch feature and mark my resolved confliction as HEAD?

Comment: `git rebase --abort` discards _all_ changes since the _beginning_ of rebase. Use it if you've decided to iinterrupt the rebase and return to the point where you were before `git rebase`. `... --cont`, well, continues the previously interrupted rebase process.

Comment: @user3159253, I want to keep rebased contents I have done.

Comment: Then you should complete the rebase with `git rebase --continue` :). In general the algorithm looks like this: `git rebase` sequently applies changes from a given branch to the new starting point. If it encounters a conflict, it stops and asks you to resolve the problem. When you have resolved a conflict, you instruct git to continue with `git rebase --continue`, until a next conflict or until the entire sequence is rebased to the new starting point.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop `rebase` in the middle, you should do the following.

1. After you've resolved all conflicting points, you should add the changes to index with `git add`, and create a new commit with `git commit`.
2. But this comming will be dangling one, so you need to mark it somehow. The easiest way is to `git tag` it with a temporary tag, but also you can simply remember it's SHA-1.
3. Then you should use `git rebase --abort` to return your branch to the state it was before the rebase
4. Now you can forcibly set the branch to the commit you've created during the merge with `git reset --hard <tag_name_or_remembered_SHA1>`.

In any case you can revert the changes with `git reset --hard`. You can check the output of `git reflog` to see the whole list of recent actions including rebase, resets and new commits.